# how to find and show data based on string inputted using spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

im new to spring jpa. 
right now im trying to make an API that show one data from my database.
how to get string input from user , and show data based on that string input?

previously i tried to show data based on id and it works.
code:

```
@GetMapping("/rating/{project_code}")
   public Optional<Project> getProject(@PathVariable long project_code){ 
   Optional<Project> getProjectCode = projectRepository.findById(project_code);
        return getProjectCode;
   }
```

but for string input i still have no idea. code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Optional<Detail> getProjectInfo(@RequestParam(value = "token") String token){
        Optional<Detail> getProjectInfoByToken = detailRepository.findById( Long.valueOf(token));
        return getProjectInfoByToken;
    }
```

i already tried to call it with postman http://localhost:8080/api/rating?token=bl4ck
but it give me ' java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"bl4ck\ 'error.
thanks for the help

Comment: You can answer your own questions here - don't edit your answer into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:
i add function in repository file and call it in my controller file

repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface DetailRepository extends JpaRepository<Detail, Long> {
    Detail findByToken(String token);
}
```

controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/rating")
    public Detail getProjectInfo(@RequestParam(value = "token") String token){
        Detail getProjectInfoByToken = detailRepository.findByToken(token);
        return getProjectInfoByToken;
    }
```